# vagrant /etc/hosts: machine IP vs localhost

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, hosts, virtual-hosts, vagrant-provision

I have a vagrant machine setup with this IP address:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: 192.168.33.11
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.hostname = "my-devenv"
...
end
```

Everything works just fine. But I am confused on the /etc/hosts file on the VM: What is the difference between using localhost and VM's IP (127.0.0.1 some-dev-site.dev vs 192.168.33.11 some-dev-site.dev)?

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 some-dev-site.dev
192.168.33.11 some-dev-site.dev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**General**

The localhost is normally always the same on different machines: 127.0.0.1 (local loopback) and the VM IP is the external IP on the 'network'. You can for example connect from your machine to your VM by accessing the VM IP, but if you connect to localhost from your machine to the VM, you end up on your own machine.

If you bind a service to 127.0.0.1 you will not be able to reach it from 'outside' of the 'machine'.

This offers probably a better explanation if you want to read more:
https://www.lifewire.com/network-computer-special-ip-address-818385

**More specific to your situation**

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I guess your question is about: what are the hostnames in the /etc/hosts of your virtual machine? That is because they don't exist in the DNS and if you are connecting to these hosts it needs to end up at the right place and that, in this case is the VM itself.

Comment: So if I understand well: when I call `some-dev-site.dev` in my local machine (which also has in its hosts: `192.168.33.11 some-dev-site.dev`) it talks to the VM using `some-dev-site.dev` then the VM translates this to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: which means at the end: the VM's IP 192.168.33.11 == the VM's 127.0.0.1

Comment: If vagrant added the 192.168.33.11 some-dev-site.dev in your local /etc/hosts on your machine, then you will access the webservice on your VM on it's external interface. When you are inside of your VM and you access some-dev-site.dev it will most likely connect to the webservice on the local loopback interface 127.0.0.1. You need to look at your /etc/hosts as a simpel local 'DNS server'. And the address 127.0.0.1 as a private IP adres only visible for the machine you're on.

Comment: And 192.168.33.11 != the VM's 127.0.0.1 those are two separate interfaces. Run the command: ifconfig on your VM and you will see something like eth0  192.168.33.11 and lo0 127.0.0.1